# what is the easiest way to remove the power supply from a Dell precision-390

Tags: hardware-failure

The fan in the power supply is making a lot of noise and I need to remove the power supply and inspect it. The wires run under the heat sink, do I need to remove the heat sink to get the wires out?

Comment: you should be able to just disconnect the wires and unscrew the psu from the case.

Answer (score 5):

Dell service manuals, which have full disassembly instructions, are available online online at support.dell.com. Here's the Precision 390 one: ftp://ftp.dell.com/Manuals/all-products/esuprt_desktop/esuprt_dell_precision_workstation/precision-390_user%27s%20guide_en-us.pdf

Unfortunately, the only relevant instruction appears to be:

> Disconnect the DC power cables from the system board and the drives.
>
> Note the routing of the DC power cables underneath the tabs in the
>   computer frame as you release the tabs and remove the cables from the
>   system  board and drives. You must route these cables properly when
>   you replace them to prevent their being pinched or crimped.

If it does turn out that you have to remove the heat sink to get the cables out - page 96 of the service manual - make sure to clean off and replace the thermal paste between the heat sink and processor. ([general thermal paste instructions](http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/333968-28-thermal-paste-removal-installation-guide))